# How to allow a disabled SelectField in WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm making a form which has fields enabled and disabled according to previous choices. However, when I disable the SelectField (meaning that it is not submitted), validation fails because of an "invalid choice". How can I let it validate even when it's not submitted?

```py
print(form.errors)
```

```py
{'linkto': ['Not a valid choice']}
```

```py
class BoardEditForm(FlaskForm):
...
    linkto = SelectField('Link to:', choices=[])
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use an `Optional` validator in the definition, e.g:

```py
from wtforms.validators import Optional
class BoardEditForm(FlaskForm):
...
    linkto = SelectField('Link to:', validators=[Optional()], choices=[])
...
```